# onstatus catches exception but mono error is ignored and client gets http status code 200

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, webclient

can someone explain the issue with exception handling in this code, it perfectly works in the local machine but it starts to behave strangely when deployed on Kubernetes. the issue is when 400 is returned from API it enters onStatus (isError) but the caller gets http status code 200, I can not understand why mono.error is ignored?

service

```
    @Override
    public Mono<Individual> getIndividualById(Long id, String clientInfo) {

        return webClient
                .get()
                .uri(
                        dbssUrl,
                        urlBuilder -> urlBuilder
                                .path("/individuals/1.0/" + id)
                                .build()
                )
                .header("clientInfo", clientInfo)
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(
                        ExceptionUtils::isNotFound,
                        clientResponse -> Mono.error(CustomException.build(INDIVIDUAL_NOT_FOUND))
                )
                .onStatus(
                        HttpStatusCode::isError,
//                        ExceptionUtils::handleUnexpectedExceptions
                        clientResponse -> clientResponse
                                .bodyToMono(APIFailResponseBody.class)
                                .flatMap(
                                        error -> Mono
                                                .error(
                                                        CustomException
                                                                .builder()
                                                                .httpStatusCode(clientResponse.statusCode())
                                                                .message(error.getMessage())
                                                                .build()
                                                )
                                )
                )
                .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<APISuccessResponseBody<Individual>>() {})
                .map(APISuccessResponseBody::getResponse);
}
```

controller

```
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<IndividualDto>> getIndividualById(
            @Parameter(description = "the id of the individual")
            @PathVariable
            Long id,

            @Parameter(description = "Client can provide a string value to include in the logs for traceability")
            @RequestHeader(
                    name = "client-info",
                    required = false,
                    defaultValue = "account-service"
            )
            String clientInfo
    ) {
        return individualsService
                .getIndividualDtoById(id, clientInfo)
                .map(individualDto -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(individualDto));
    }
```

global exception handler

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
    public ErrorResponse handleCustomException(CustomException exception,
                                               ServerHttpRequest httpRequest) {
        log.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);

        return ErrorResponse
                .builder(exception, exception.getHttpStatusCode(), exception.getMessage())
                .title(exception.getTitle())
                .instance(URI.create(httpRequest.getPath().value()))
                .type(URI.create("https://confluence.mycompany.com/")) 
                .property("code", exception.getCode())
                .build();
    }

}
```